# How to iterate over a string and push characters to an object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a function where I accept a string that contains vowels and iterate over it then push the vowels into an object. I am using a forEach loop (I cannot use any other type of loop) to go over each character to check the letter and see if its a vowel and if it is, I set the vowel character equal to the object key and the number of times the vowel occurs will be the value. Here is my code so far:

```
function vowelCount(str) {
  let obj = {}
  str.split(' ')
  str.forEach(function(val) {
    obj.val = 'hi'
    
  })
  return obj
}
```

I know there is a lot more work needed to be done, but I am unsure of how to set the keys equal to the vowels and the occurrences as the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`obj.val` is accessing property `val` of `obj`, so to access it dynamically, it should be `obj[val]`

```js
function isVowel(char) {
  return "aeiou".includes(char)
}

function vowelCount(str) {
  let obj = {}
  str.split("").forEach(function (val) {
    if (isVowel(val)) {
      obj[val] = (obj[val] || 0) + 1
    }
  })
  return obj
}

console.log(vowelCount("aeiouaeiouaaaii"))
```

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you

Comment: Would you mind explaining this line of code for me please:  obj[val] = (obj[val] || 0) + 1

Comment: @azaria.dee `(obj[val] || 0)` is getting the value of `obj[val]`, if it is undefined, use 0 as default

Answer (score 2):

```
function vowelCount(str) {
  const vowels = { a: 0, e: 0, i: 0, o: 0, u: 0 };

  str.split('').forEach((ch) => {
    if (vowels[ch]) {
      vowelCount++;
    }
  });

  return vowels;
}
```

If you want you can always filter the values to exclude the zero counts.
And don't be scared of other functions used for iterations like:

```
const vowelCount = (str = '') =>
  str.split('').reduce(
    (vowels, ch) => {
      if (vowels[ch]) {
        vowels[ch]++;
      }
      return vowels;
    },
    { a: 0, e: 0, i: 0, o: 0, u: 0 }
  );
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You really helped clear up that issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a vowel set of all vowels, then iterate over the supplied string `str` and add the count based on the existing count in the `obj` object:

```js
function vowelCount(str) {
  let obj = {}
  const chars = str.toLocaleLowerCase().split('');
  const vowels = new Set(["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]);
  chars.forEach(c => {
    if (vowels.has(c)) {
      obj[c] = (obj[c] || 0) + 1;
    }
  });
  return obj
}
console.log(vowelCount("Hello World! this is a function to count vowels"));
```